# Seeding entities in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, domain-driven-design

I am making a simple role-permission authentication application using ASP.NET Core Web API. I am using Entity Framework Core in migrating my domain entities to the database. While making the configurations and after that generating migrations, it can't seed the entity permission because there is no value provided for the required entity `RoleId`.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

using UserPermissionAPI.Domain.Role;
using UserPermissionAPI.Domain.Role.ValueObjects;
using UserPermissionAPI.Domain.UserRoleDomain.Common.Constants;
using UserPermissionAPI.Domain.UserRoleDomain.Role.Entities;
using UserPermissionAPI.Domain.UserRoleDomain.Role.ValueObjects;

namespace UserPermissionAPI.Infrastructure.Persistence.Configuration;

public sealed class RoleConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
    {
        ConfigureRoleTable(builder);
        ConfigurePermissionTable(builder);
        ConfigureMemberJoinTable(builder);
    }

    private static void ConfigureRoleTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Roles");
        builder.HasKey(u => u.Id);

        builder
            .Property(d => d.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value,
                value => RoleId.Create(value));

        builder
            .Property(d => d.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        IEnumerable<Role> roles = Enum
            .GetValues<RoleEnum>()
            .Select(p => Role.Create(
                RoleId.Create((int)p),
                p.ToString()
            ));

        builder
            .HasData(roles);
    }

    private static void ConfigurePermissionTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
    {
        builder
            .OwnsMany(d => d.Permissions, builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .ToTable("Permissions");

                builder
                    .WithOwner()
                    .HasForeignKey("RoleId");

                builder
                    .Property(u => u.Id)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever()
                    .HasConversion(
                        id => id.Value,
                        value => PermissionId.Create(value));

                builder
                    .Property(d => d.Name)
                    .HasMaxLength(100);

                IEnumerable<Permission> permissions = Enum
                    .GetValues<PermissionEnum>()
                    .Select(p => Permission.Create(
                        PermissionId.Create((int)p),
                        p.ToString())
                    );

                builder
                    .HasData(permissions);
            });

        builder.Metadata
            .FindNavigation(nameof(Role.Permissions))!
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
```

The error in generating migrations:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: The seed entity for entity type 'Permission' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'RoleId'.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateData(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelRuntimeInitializer.Initialize(IModel model, Boolean designTime, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 validationLogger)         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> The seed entity for entity type 'Permission' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'RoleId'.

Comment: Use `builder.Property(d => d.Id).HasColumnName("RoleId");`

Comment: @ecemcy still got the same error.

Comment: Can you show what the ```Permission``` and ```Role``` entities look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

You're converting an Enum Value to an Entity which has a RoleId, while not setting RoleId on the conversion. EF Core Requires Permission.RoleId to be set because it is a required relationship to Role.

You can fix the error by adding an Id pointing to a role existing in database or removing the relationship alltogether.

Comment: Both enum values starts at 1.

Comment: @JohnKenethPaluca updated my answer since i missed some details before